# How to get key from ng-options keyValue?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following data in as `cars`. I want to get the selected key from the dropdown. Like when User selects `Ford`, it should give me `car01`. I want to get the key and value both from dropdown.
I 'm trying to use `{{x}}`, but it's showing nothing.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Select a car:</p>

<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x for (x, y) in cars">
</select>

<h1>You selected: {{selectedCar.brand}}</h1>
<h2>Model: {{selectedCar.model}}</h2>
<h3>Color: {{selectedCar.color}}</h3>
<p>ColorKey: {{x}}</p>
<p>Note that the selected value represents an object.</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = {
        car01 : {brand : "Ford", model : "Mustang", color : "red"},
        car02 : {brand : "Fiat", model : "500", color : "white"},
        car03 : {brand : "Volvo", model : "XC90", color : "black"}
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it like this

```
<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x as y.brand  for (x, y) in cars">
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.cars = {
        car01 : {brand : "Ford", model : "Mustang", color : "red"},
        car02 : {brand : "Fiat", model : "500", color : "white"},
        car03 : {brand : "Volvo", model : "XC90", color : "black"}
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Select a car:</p>

<select ng-model="selectedCar" ng-options="x as y.brand for (x, y) in cars">
</select>

{{selectedCar}} 

<h1>You selected: {{cars[selectedCar].brand}}</h1>
<h2>Model: {{cars[selectedCar].model}}</h2>
<h3>Color: {{cars[selectedCar].color}}</h3>
<p>ColorKey: {{selectedCar}}</p>
<p>Note that the selected value represents an object.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Then How will I get brand, model and color ?

Comment: @viveknuna check the demo again

Comment: Why can't I directly use {{selectedCar.brand}}

Comment: because `selectedCar` is now assigned to key value